# Android SyncAdapter logic for onPerformSync

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-syncadapter

I have a local SQLite DB, and a few ContentProviders for my tables.
What exactly should I code inside the onPerformSync in order to have the local tables synced with the remote tables (located on a remote server in a MySQL database) ?
I need bi-directional syncing. The app will be used on multiple devices, by multiple users at the same time, and all of the devices must sync with the same remote DB tables, in this way: SEND all that is local to remote, and GET the part that regards the specific device/user, from remote to local.

Can I use PHP on the server side? Because I assume I wont directly access the MySQL database from the device...? So I will probably send/receive some JSON through a webservice kind of approach?

Please show me an example of what I should perform in onPerformSync method.
Here is an example from a tutorial I found:

```
@Override
  public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
      ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

      String authtoken = null;
      try {
          authtoken = mAccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account,
              AuthenticatorActivity.PARAM_AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, true);

          // Dummy sample. Do whatever you want in this method.
          // Now I assume here I should do/call my methods that DO SOMETHING...
          // What exactly does a method that does the syncing look like?

          List data = fetchData(authtoken);
          syncRemoteDeleted(data);
          syncFromServerToLocalStorage(data);
          syncDirtyToServer(authtoken, getDirtyList(mContentResolver));

      } catch (Exception e) {
          handleException(authtoken, e, syncResult);
      }
  }
```

So what should I do in "syncRemoteDeleted(data)" method for example?
Please share some code with me because I'm in the dark here.

Thank you

Comment: check this link, it helps. http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/

Comment: Any chance that someone can point me into the direction of an example using a regular server, with a mySQL DB server, pergaps PHP on the server side? That would help me A LOT

Comment: @Akhil - thanks for the idea, but that example uses a Parse.com API for authentication and I can only assume that is uses parse as DB server. And that does not help me, since I need something for a server with PHP :(. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/sschendel/SyncManagerAndroid.  It links to a demo app.  This library includes a 2 way sync implementation.  Sounds like you still need to build the server API.  I have had success with Python Flask framework and RESTful plugin (http://flask.pocoo.org/ http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for quick and simple RESTful API to databases.